# addCategoryFilter() returns null

Tags: product, category, collection, magento-1, product-collection

I have a method, that returns me a lowest price product and it works fine:

```
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $productCollection */
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $productCollection = $product->getCollection();
    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setOrder('price', 'ASC')->load();
    $productCollection->getSelect()->limit(1);
    $product = $productCollection->getFirstItem();
    if ($product->getId() != $productId) {
        return $product;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

But if I add filtering by category, it`s return NULL

```
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category */
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $category->load($categoryId);

    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $productCollection */
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $productCollection = $product->getCollection();
    $productCollection->addCategoryFilter($category);
    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setOrder('price', 'ASC')->load();
    $productCollection->getSelect()->limit(1);
    $product = $productCollection->getFirstItem();
    if ($product->getId() != $productId) {
        return $product;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find ans in below link. I have same issue which i have fixed from [URL](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24436/product-collection-for-default-category).

also you can use

```
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
                    array('in' => $currentCategoryId),
            ))
```

Comment: Thank you! The solution is to adding `$category->setIsAnchor(true);` after loading category